# Can I use Angular.js code done for standard website as it is in Ionic project?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a standard Angular JS website with Node which client has invested for years. Can we simply pick up the angular controllers from website code and use them in ionic project? I tried that but got some directive issues which I have to remove. Before investing further time into it I thought it would be better to get an opinion from experts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically angular is crossplatform and can be used on whatever device supporting it.
Practically you may have to adapt you angularjs code to the device functionning.   so in this case with ionic.
 the good thing in your situation is that the server side stays the same. so you can use the same node server for both app and website.

Comment: That mean angular controllers cannot be used as is? There need to be some modification done based on the directives which are available in ionic?

Comment: Yes, we can re-use majority of the code, but will need to do some changes for the functionalities which are not supported by IONIC or IONIC has some substitute for it.